# “I had a whole life” or “I have had a whole life”. Can you help me?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

Last night I read a book, called *The Hunger Games*,  and it was write “I had a whole life.”

I am questioning myself because for me *Having a whole life* is related to the present, it means she has had a whole life before, it’s her experience. Tell me if I am wrong.

I know that if the action (to have a whole life) takes place before another action, we will use the past perfect:

> “She had had a whole life before they took it from her.”

So can you tell me if “I had a whole life” is correct or do we have to say:

> “I have had a whole life”

Or maybe both are correct?

I have difficulties to make the difference between the past simple and the present perfect.

Comment: Can you tell us the title of the book and give more context (what was happening when she said this)?

Comment: The book is the hunger games. She said that she had a whole life to another people. 
She tell him that before now she had a whole life and they took it from her. 

So i do not understand why we dont use present perfect (i’ve had a whole life) or past perfect (i had had a whole life)

Comment: By the way, in English, we report speech with double quotes "like this", not chevrons or guillemets « like this ».

Comment: I'm afraid your explanation doesn't make sense. Depending on the context, any of your suggestions might work. So might the original version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The present tense is *I have a whole life.*

The character says "I had a whole life." (She used to have a full life, and it has been taken away from her). I assume *whole* refers to the kind of life she had, and 'taking it from her' means that she was made to accept a different lifestyle, not that her life ended.

She would only say "I have had a whole life" if she thought she was about to die and her life was almost over.

Comment: Thank you kate bunting for your answer I understand now